# Latex; color/highlight list of words in PDF

Tags: texify

Suppose I have a list of words and a tex-document.
Now I want to color every occurrence of these words in the PDF created by pdftexify.

How to do that?

Comment: One possibility: create a macro that colors its argument. Then use search/replace in your editor (or with a script) to insert the macro calls.. Others may suggest a TeX solution.Note: @StevenB.Segletes comment points exactly to these solutions.